# Package file is invalid when downloading my app at Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-studio

I just published a new app to the Google Play. The problem is that I can't install it in any device because whenever I try to download it, I receive a "Package file is invalid" error.

I tried to clean the Google Play cache and data but it didn't work. I also tried to download it in several different devices and wifi networks. Still I get the error.

I was wondering what could be possible reasons for this error.

When I opened the logcat after trying to download the app from Google Play, I see the following error:

```
Signature check failed, aboring installation.
```

What could be causing this? Do I have to use a License Key within my app? Because I didn't do that. I just followed the signing tutorial and used the Android Studio to generate the signed APK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Play web servers are serving corrupted package files for lots of apps, this weekend.  (Lots of people on Twitter are grumbling about it.)  While many different error conditions can lead to the "Package file is invalid" and "Signature check failed" error messages, your issue is almost certainly this problem at Google that they'll (hopefully) fix in the next day or two.

I [did some investigation into this issue](http://cafbit.com/entry/android_package_file_is_invalid), and found that the corruption was present in the data stream when packet sniffing at my router, before it even reached my devices.